# Add a submodule with Gitpython

Tags: gitpython

How can I add a submodule with Gitpython?
I know how I add it the normal way but I do not find any help in the docs from Gitpython how I can add it with the lib.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [Gitpython API](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.objects.submodule.base.Submodule.add),
As it said, you can do:

```py
from git import Repo, Submodule

repo = Repo(ROOT_REPO_PATH)

Submodule.add(repo, SUBMODULE_NAME, SUBMODULE_PATH, SUBMODULE_URL)
```

Comment: If you don't have a remote URL and are just trying to add a local path (i.e. for a unit test fixture), you can use `repo.git.submodule('add', '/local/path')`